# Making two Haskell distributed-process programs connect to each other

Tags: haskell

I've looked at some simple tutorials for distributed-process, "Cloud Haskell", and was wondering if I could construct a chat system with distributed process. So my first thought was that I should just see if I can send messages between two instances of the same program.

But I have no idea how to make two different distributed-process programs connect to each other. How do I do that? Can I even use distributed-process for this or do I have to use somehing else on a level "lower"?

Thank you for all answers!

Comment: Have you read the [echo server tutorial](http://haskell-distributed.github.io/tutorials/tutorial-NT2.html)? This might give you some idea.

Comment: Zeta, this was a bit what was I looking for, but I would like to just use things like newChan, sendChan and receiveChan. I guess I can build something on top of what was described in your link.